# Synonym for I will get back to you or I come back to you?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

What is the synonym for saying I will get back to you or I come back to you?

Comment: Those are the phrases we typically use; there really isn't a single-word synonym. My Indian colleagues say "I'll *revert* (or *revert back*) on that shortly", but I personally *loathe* that usage.

Comment: @DanBron Are there any better ways of rephrasing this sentence if single word synonym doesn't exist.

Comment: Those are really the most common, clearest, and "best" ways. What's bothering you about them? Do you just want a *different* (not *better*) way to say it, because you feel you've said "I'll *get back to you*" too often, or something? I suppose "I'll *return* to you on that" is a common alternative.

Comment: @DanBron I will get back to you has been used quite often, was pondering whether there exist a synonym for better ways of using this.

Comment: "I'll *return* to you" on that, "I'll *follow-up* shortly", "Let me *take that away*" (in a meeting, implying but not explicitly stating you'll get back), etc. But be warned: creative language *sounds like* creatives language, and it more likely to get noticed (and judged) than common  phrases which, even when repeated frequently, rarely draw attention to themselves.

Comment: *I (We) will **revisit*** -- as it is fashionable today.

Comment: @Kris, in American professional lingo, "revisit" means "table for now, investigate again at a later time", it's a polite way way of saying "take it outside, boys" (i.e. "let's not talk about that now"). If you asked me a question and I responded "I'll get back to you", there's an implied promise that I'll return with a solution or answer; no such promise is implied by "revisit". To the contrary, if replied to your question with  "I'll revisit that", I would be conveying "I don't know what to do with that, and I *may* look at it later, but I definitely don't want to talk or think about it now".

Comment: Maybe a more concise way of putting it is: when someone says "let's *revisit* that later" in a meeting, it almost always means "right now, that's just a *distraction*".

Comment: What is the contextual situation for these? In a meeting? At your desk? On the phone? In an e-mail? Something else?

Comment: @jxh Well some of the situations this being used are when a customer or client communicates by email, phone or when they meet at desk or when they have queries in a meeting.

Answer (score 4):

Without any context, the single word that comes to my mind is ***follow-up***, which means to continue something later that has already been started.

> I will be sure to *follow-up* soon.

If you want to postpone answering a question until later during a discussion (like in a presentation or a meeting), you can use ***circle back***.

> That's a good point, but let's *circle back* to that later.

If you want to answer the question after the meeting is over, you can request to ***take it offline***.

> Good question, but it is beyond the scope of this discussion. Let's *take it offline*.

If you are answering the phone, but are currently busy, you can first ask them to ***hold***, or if you know it will be a while, you can promise to ***call back***.

> I am busy with someone else right now, can you *hold* for a bit?
>   I am in the middle of something important, may I *call you back*?

Answer (score 1):

"Reply" or "Respond" are single word equivalents for the first phrase you cite, "get back to you".

"Come back to you" is not (at least in my experience) a common idiom, and in its more literal sense, could be replaced by the single word "return".

Comment: In American business jargon, "get back to you" connotes *with a solution or at least a firm answer*, whereas "reply" is much weaker, merely a response. If you asked me a question, I could *reply* with "I'll get back to you on that", which means, later, I'm going to follow-up with "yes", "no", or "42".

Comment: Dan, sometimes it means that. In my own experience, "I'll get back to you" sometimes means, "I'm too busy to deal with that right now. I expect I'll also be too busy to deal with that this afternoon, and tomorrow and the next day aren't looking good, either." Given the context provided by the OP, I'm sticking by my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For an action item such as you'd use in an email response, I prefer follow up with no hyphen. 
"Stay tuned for more information as we will follow up in the coming months." Follow-up (with hyphen) is more common as a noun (as in, "The Times published a follow-up on that sewage treatment story you liked").

I too have noticed the "revert" and "revert back" usage and while I don't like it either, I admire it's efficiency. I hear it from colleagues in Asia.